# Selenium Python can't connect to website with proxy

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with chrome driver and connect to websites using proxy, but for some odd reason chrome gives back an error, that either connection was reset or connection timed out or this site cant be reached and so on.. used many proxies, so I doubt that the proxy server is at fault.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = r'C:/Users\seife\Documents\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'
PROXY = "177.202.59.58:8080"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Here's how the page looks:

[image: Chrome error page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#you need to import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = r'C:/Users\seife\Documents\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'
PROXY = "177.202.59.58:8080"  #free proxies sometimes don't work, I tried with netherland's proxy, and it worked
chrome_options = Options()   #here is the change
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com")   #and here is the change, just https
```

Comment: I put the changes, used many proxies including yours and it still won't connect ;/ , whats your chrome version??, anyways thanks for your help, I appreciate it!.

Comment: Try using different proxies from here https://www.sslproxies.org/ . My chrome version is 83. Did you even tried changing headers?

Comment: Try changing user agent as well. You can get free user agents from user-agents.net or you can use fake_headers module. "chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user-agent}')"something like this

Comment: I had v.81 chromedriver, maybe I was outdated idk. it worked but its super slow?, probably because of a free proxy.

Comment: Yeah,free proxies are mostly slow, you can use VPN as well